# How to add own tags using the tagify plugin, 'Mix text & tags' in particular

Tags: tags, hashtag, input-field

I'm creating an input field mixed with tags and inputs using the tagify plugin- section-mix- (see: https://yaireo.github.io/tagify/#section-mix).

The problem is:

> Note that tags can only be created if the value matches any of the whitelisted item's value.

I want to add them myself by hitting enter just as in the other examples in the link. Any idea how to solve this with tagify?

**HTML**

```html
<textarea name='mix'>@cartman and @kyle do not know #homer who is #lisa</textarea>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
var input = document.querySelector('[name=mix]'),
// init Tagify script on the above inputs
tagify = new Tagify(input, {
    mode       : 'mix',  // <--  Enable mixed-content
    pattern    : /@/,  // <--  Tag words which start with # (can be a String instead of Regex)
    whitelist  : [
        {
            value: 'Homer'
        }
    ],
    dropdown   : {
        enabled : 1
    }
})

var whitelist_2 = ['Homer', 'Marge', 'Bart', 'Lisa', 'Maggie', 'Mr. Burns', 'Ned', 'Milhouse', 'Moe'];

// A good place to pull server suggestion list accoring to the prefix/value
tagify.on('input', function(e){
var prefix = e.detail.prefix;

    if( prefix == '#' )
        tagify.settings.whitelist = whitelist_2;

    if( e.detail.value.length > 1 )
        tagify.dropdown.show.call(tagify, e.detail.value);
}
```

Comment: Cleaned up grammar, spelling, and code formatting.

Comment: Currently you cannot, but it is on the roadmap. Follow [this discussion](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify/issues/186) for updates.

Answer (score 0):

*Tagify* now supports creating new tags in *mix-mode* as of version `3.4.0`

See [tagify's example page](https://yaireo.github.io/tagify/#section-mix)

---

**UPDATE 24 FEB, 2020**

Currently only tags without spaces can be added due to unresolved complexity in the implementation of how adding new tags in mix-mode works. I will address this soon.